# On OS X, how can I log in to SharePoint 2007 as a domain user using Chrome or FireFox?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using a Mac running OS X 10.9.1, and attempting to log in to a SharePoint 2007 site on a windows domain.

If I use Safari, I access the site (`http://mySharePointSite/`) and am prompted by the browser for a username and password.  I enter 'MYDOMAIN\myUsername' and my password, and am logged in successfully.

If I start a Windows VM, and log in to the domain, then use Internet Explorer, Chrome, or FireFox to access the site, I am prompted by the browser for a username and password.  I enter 'MYDOMAIN\myUsername' and my password, and am logged in successfully.

My problem is that if I attempt to access the site from OS X using Chrome or FireFox, I am prompted for my username and password, but entering 'MYDOMAIN\myUsername' and my password does not work - the box simply refreshes and asks me to enter my credentials again, and I am unable to login.

How can I login to this SharePoint 2007 site using Chrome or Firefox on OS X, and what would be preventing it?  This does not seem to be a common problem, so I am not sure if the issue is on my side, or on the SharePoint server configuration side.

Comment: Is OSX on the domain in the same way? Can you login without the `mydomain` prefix?

Comment: OSX is not on the domain (I didn't realize that was possible, so on the side, I'll investigate that).  I can not login without the `mydomain` prefix, on Windows or OSX.

Comment: Logging into the Active Directory server using OSX does not change the behavior.